# Measure scanning time - Canon scanner

Tags: process, scanner

I have a [CanoScan lide 25 scanner](http://www.usa.canon.com/consumer/controller?act=ModelInfoAct&fcategoryid=119&modelid=11463) . How can i measure the time to scan a document (trying different dpi) . Any command line tools ? Either Windows or Linux ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux systems, use the [`time`](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?1+time) command to run a command and output some basic system time stats after the command finishes.  You'll need a commandline to initiate the scan.

```
user@host:$ time some-command arg1 arg2 arg3
<some-command output>

real    0m1.140s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.016s
```

- **real** is the elapsed real ("wall") time the process takes to run, start-to-finish;
- **user** is the time the process used directly in user-mode (ie, not counting time the CPU spent servicing other processes);
- **sys** is the time the process used directly in kernel-mode (again, not counting time the CPU spent on other processes).

`time` can summarize lots of other system-resource usage on processes; see [`man time`](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?1+time) on your system for details and options.

This also works in the [Cygwin unix environment](http://www.cygwin.com/) for Windows if you can locate a commandline tool for grabbing a scan.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i measure the time to scan a
>   document

This sure works for your scans, whether in Windows or Linux:

[image]

---

If you want a software solution:

**[TimeLeft](http://www.timeleft.info/)** is a versatile desktop utility - it can be used as a countdown clock, reminder, clock, alarm clock, tray clock, **stopwatch**, timer, sticker, auction watch, work days/hours countdown clock and time synchronization utility.

*TimeLeft is freeware (Windows only).*

... from the command line, you can use this:

**[STOPWATCH](http://www.jfitz.com/dos/index.html#STOPWATCH)** can be used to calculate the elapsed time, (in seconds), in a batch file. It does this by redirecting the current time out to a file when the "start" command is given, and then reading that time back in when a "stop" command is given. For example:

```
C:\>stopwatch start > timestamp.txt
... other batch commands here ...
C:\>stopwatch stop < timestamp.txt
10
```

Note that the output from the stop command can be piped or redirected to a program or file if required, and multiple "stop" commands can be executed to get intermediate timestamps. If you want to save the output of the "stopwatch stop" command to a variable, DOS/Windows doesn't make things easy for you. Here's an example that includes an ugly workaround to get the elapsed time into a variable called "elapsed_time":

```
@echo off
stopwatch start > timestamp.txt
... other batch commands here ...
stopwatch stop < timestamp.txt > elapsed.txt
for /F %%a in ('type elapsed.txt') do set /a elapsed_time=%%a
echo %elapsed_time%
```